# Compressing image using canvas is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When trying to compress a photo using `Chrome`, i get a good result where 8M photo turns to be 1.2M on desktop.

When trying the same on `Safari` iPhone, the photo size stay almost the same and is even becomes 100kb larger .

```
//read input , where minSize is 2, and photos are larger
function getURLS(inputs,index,compressed,callback,minSize) {
  for (let k=0;k<inputs.files.length;k++)
  {
        var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function(e)
              {
               let file =  e.target.result;
               var newIndex = k ;
               if(index > -1 ) newIndex=index;
               var dic = {};
               dic["index"]=newIndex;
               dic["base64"]=file;
               dic["file"]=inputs.files[k];
               console.log("size before:", inputs.files[k].size/1024/1024),dic["index"] ;
                 if(compressed===true){
                   let sizeMB = Math.abs(inputs.files[k].size/1024/1024);
                       if(sizeMB<minSize) callback(dic);
                       else startCompression(dic,callback);
                 }
                 else{
                    callback(dic);
                 }
              }
        reader.readAsDataURL(inputs.files[k]);
   }
}



function startCompression(dic,callback){
  var file = dic["base64"];
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = compressImg(img);
     canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
       //var finalsrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                   var reader = new FileReader();
                   reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                   reader.onloadend = function() {
                        var finalblob = blob;
                        finalblob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                        finalblob.name = "r"+ simpleUnique();
                        dic["file"]=finalblob;
                        dic["base64"]=reader.result;
                        let sizeMB =  blob.size/1024/1024 ;
                        console.log("compressed to:",sizeMB,dic["index"]);
                        canvas.parentElement.removeChild(canvas);
                         callback(dic);
                  }
     }, 'image/jpeg', 0.9);
  };
  img.src = file;
}



function compressImg(img){

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  oWidth = img.naturalWidth,
  oHeight = img.naturalHeight,
  ratio = oWidth / oHeight,
  width = oWidth,
  height = Math.round(width / ratio);
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.className = 'temp-cnv';
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  return canvas;
}
```

example of results on iPhone:

```
[Log] size before: – 0.5767936706542969 – 4  
[Log] size before: – 2.6416501998901367 – 1  
[Log] size before: – 3.1758155822753906 – 0  
[Log] size before: – 3.703227996826172 – 2  
[Log] size before: – 3.3884010314941406 – 3  
[Log] compressed to: – 2.669351577758789 – 1   
[Log] compressed to: – 3.197432518005371 – 0   
[Log] compressed to: – 3.7769737243652344 – 2   
[Log] compressed to: – 3.4392786026000977 – 3
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
Do I measure size wrong? do I need to reduce quality more ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the `canvas` width/height to be **smaller** than original photo. It was the same so things didn't change that much.